# VBA Compatibility between different Office Versions

Tags: vba, excel

Sorry if this is a silly question.

What can I do to make my VBA code work on Office 2003/2007/2010 ?

Can it be done or should I create different VBA code for each?

I use

1. WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1
2. Make a lot of Windows API Calls
3. Have five references to libraries
4. wininet.dll
5. kernel32
6. Outlook.Application
7. InternetExplorer.Application

I'm developing on Office 2007 but users with Office 2010 cant run the code. Not sure about users runnning other office versions.

I have also seen that one can create an Excel-Addin in Visual Studio but I dont have a lot of experience in that area.

Thx for any suggestions.

Comment: if you're usingh Win32 API calls, and the Office 2010 users are using 64-bit Windows those API calls won't run as the declarations don't exist. Also, check the references in the VB project on the machine of the users with Office 2010, as if the IE versions are different this will also fail!

Comment: There are significant differences in object model which means that objects that exist in one version don't exist in the other. It is mind-numbingly annoying. Example: a Shape of type Picture became a Shape of type Placeholder of type Picture - so code that used to look for pictures stops working. And that's before we're talking 32/64, and communication with other applications / versions.

Comment: Thx for your reply. I'm starting to wonder if I should not write a normal c# application for this.

Comment: perhaps, for small amounts of code you can just use Conditional Compilation such as **#If Application.version>n then** ...

Comment: It also seems like using late binding instead of early binding might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for different versions of Excel, you can just use Conditional Compilation such as `#If Application.version>n then`

However, for any users who have Win64 systems, you will have to provide different methods of calling the API functions.

Your best bet is to try and manipulate Excel using Automation either from .NET using Office.Interop, or VSTO.